# Rest Angular and Charts API - Need opinion

Tags: java, angularjs, charts, restangular

We are re-building the current product.

1.) Main focus is on UI, `Graphical Representation`

2.) UI should be `responsive`, `widget` like structures.

3.) Graphs should be re-loaded with data at `every n seconds`

I have gone through few charts API,

[angular-nvd3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/)

[fusioncharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/angularjs-charts/#/demos/ex1) // not free

`Rest Service` will be exposed, Json data will be return. Multiple types of graphs will be used. (Bars/Spikes etc.)

**Need help on choosing the good API for Charts that can be integrated with Rest Angular.**

**Also anything better for widget sort of structure, should adjust according to screen's. Widgets will be appearing on big screens as well.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ZingChart may be an option worth considering. The [AngularJS Charts Directive page](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/reference/angularjs-charts/) contains chart examples that should provide responses to your 3 main concerns.

Full disclosure: I'm on the ZingChart team, so feel free to reach out if you have additional questions on this option.

Comment: yes i do have questions, how can i reach you, pls let me know

Comment: merrily@zingchart or contact us through the form on http://www.zingchart.com/contact-us/

Comment: @Merrily can you please see my question maybe you have an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256487/i-want-to-change-the-chart-for-each-city-or-subcity-selected